# Change date of commit from raw commit

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am trying to change the date my commits on Bitbucket. I am able to do this like this:

```
git filter-branch --env-filter \
    'if [ $GIT_COMMIT = 119f9ecf58069b265ab22f1f97d2b648faf932e0 ]
     then
         export GIT_AUTHOR_DATE="Fri Jan 2 21:38:53 2009 -0800"
         export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="Sat May 19 01:01:01 2007 -0700"
     fi'
```

however, this only changes the dates from the commits page, and not when accessing the raw commit info of the commit.

is there anyway I can change the date from inside the raw commit?

EDIT:
from inside the details of the commit, there's an option of view raw commit.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "raw commit"?

Comment: Hi @evolutionxbox I posted a picture, this is shown on the right when you enter the details of the commit.

Comment: How are you getting to the commit page after the change? Any change to a commit, by design, gives it (and any of its "descendants") a new commit hash, so if you're just going back to the same commit hash, it won't ever change.

Comment: using the new commit hash,  in raw, it is still giving the date of the previous/edited commit.

Comment: The filter-branch command looks fine. You will have to use `--force` or similar (`--force-with-lease`) when pushing the rewritten branch(es). Note that you're only changing the date on *one commit*, specifically `119f9ecf58069b265ab22f1f97d2b648faf932e0`. Once filtered, none of the *new* commits will ever have that hash ID.